# Error message for StorageResource type

Tags: java

I've been trying to work on this problem for a while now but to no avail. When I run the code I get this error message: incompatible types: edu.duke.StorageResource cannot be converted to java.lang.String on line `String geneList = FMG.storeAll(dna);`. Does this mean I'm trying to make edu.duke object work with a java.lang.String type object? What would we go about resolving this issue?

Here's my code so far:

```
package coursera_java_duke;
import java.io.*;
import edu.duke.FileResource;
import edu.duke.StorageResource;
import edu.duke.DirectoryResource;

public class FindMultiGenes5 {
    public int findStopIndex(String dna, int index) {
        int stop1 = dna.indexOf("TGA", index);
        if (stop1 == -1 || (stop1 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop1 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop2 = dna.indexOf("TAA", index);
        if (stop2 == -1 || (stop2 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop2 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop3 = dna.indexOf("TAG", index);
        if (stop3 == -1 || (stop3 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop3 = dna.length();
        }
        return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3));
    }

    public StorageResource storeAll(String dna) {

        //CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCAdna = "CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA";
        String geneAL = new String();
        String sequence = dna.toUpperCase();
        StorageResource store = new StorageResource();
        int index = 0;


        while (true) {
            index = sequence.indexOf("ATG", index);
            if (index == -1)
                break;

            int stop = findStopIndex(sequence, index + 3);

            if (stop != sequence.length()) {
                String gene = dna.substring(index, stop + 3);
                store.add(gene);
                //index = sequence.substring(index, stop + 3).length();
            index = stop + 3; // start at the end of the stop codon
          }else{  index = index + 3;
        }

    }
    return store;//System.out.println(sequence);
    }
   public void testStorageFinder() {
      DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
      StorageResource dnaStore = new StorageResource(); 
    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
        String s = fr.asString();
        dnaStore = storeAll(s);
        printGenes(dnaStore);
    }


        System.out.println("size = " + dnaStore.size());

    }  
  public String readStrFromFile(){

        FileResource readFile = new FileResource();

        String DNA = readFile.asString();

        //System.out.println("DNA: " + DNA);

        return DNA;

    }//end readStrFromFile() method;
  public float calCGRatio(String gene){

        gene = gene.toUpperCase();  
        int len = gene.length();
        int CGCount = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){

            if(gene.charAt(i) == 'C' || gene.charAt(i) == 'G')
                CGCount++;

        }//end for loop

        System.out.println("CGCount " + CGCount + " Length: " + len + " Ratio: " + (float)CGCount/len);
        return (float)CGCount/len;
    }//end of calCGRatio() method;
    public void printGenes(StorageResource sr){

        //create a FindMultiGenesFile object FMG
        FindMultiGenes5 FMG = new FindMultiGenes5();

        //read a DNA sequence from file
        String dna = FMG.readStrFromFile();

        String geneList = FMG.storeAll(dna);

        //store all genes into a document
        StorageResource dnaStore = new StorageResource();

        System.out.println("\n There are " + geneList.size() + " genes. ");

        int longerthan60 = 0;
        int CGGreaterthan35 = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<geneList.size(); i++){

            if(!dnaStore.contains(geneList.get(i)))
                dnaStore.add(geneList.get(i));

            if(geneList.get(i).length() > 60) longerthan60++;
            if(FMG.calCGRatio(geneList.get(i)) > 0.35) CGGreaterthan35++;

        }

        System.out.println("dnaStore.size: " + dnaStore.size());


        System.out.println("\n There are " + dnaStore.size() + " genes. ");
        System.out.println("There are " + longerthan60 + " genes longer than 60.");
        System.out.println("There are " + CGGreaterthan35 + " genes with CG ratio greater than 0.35.");
    }//end main();
}
```

Comment: you don't have a main method calling your code, so we don't even know what is running. we also don't know the input.

Comment: I am a bit confused in understanding this. 1: Not sure what the edu packages are, but without those people can't test your code. 2: The code doesn't look like it will work at all. Those 2 might be just me, but there is also no place where you would print the output you seem to expect, fx "3 : atgtaa".

Answer (score 0):

I found your post as I am also doing a similar course at Duke using those edu.duke libraries.

When I get that error message it is because I'm using the wrong method to access it.

Try FMD.data() to get an iterable of all of the gene strings.